# Cursor not functioning correctly in IE11 select inputs

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, mouse-cursor

Please see fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ajjp/b7M2H/

```
<div>
    <select>
       <option> Option 1 </option>
       <option> Option 2 </option>
       <option> Option 3 </option>
       <option> Option 4 </option>
       <option> Option 5 </option>
       <option> Option 6 </option>
       <option> Option 7 </option>
   </select>
</div>
<div>
   <input>
   </input>
</div>
```

In Internet Explorer 11 the cursor property changes when hovering over a select option that is over the input beneath.  Hoping there is a simple CSS solution.

Comment: what an annoying behaviour. Not even this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/b7M2H/3/

Comment: when you alter your html structure, you could something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/b7M2H/4/ but this is quite ugly

Comment: Thanks @NicoO!  Agree that adding <br /> tags throughout would be suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an IE bug that seems to persist in every version - z-index and absolute positioning will not work.

Since it doesn't cripple functionality I say let it be, however if you insist on fixing it your best bet is to use a JQuery dropdown alternative such as [this one](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/).

Comment: Thanks!  It's amazing that they haven't fixed it after all these years.  I'm using Angular and would like to avoid a JQuery dependency if possible so looks like IE users will just have to deal with it...or change browsers.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap then, you can find Angular alternatives here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ or this little plugin https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns again for Angular.