# IE strange behavior on textarea and select?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, styles

I have strange IE behavior on cursor property css?

Here is the code, this is just simple inline style to show what is the problem?

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<select>
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>John</option>
<option>John</option>
<option>John</option>
<option>John</option>
<option>John</option>
<option>John</option>
</select>
</div>
<textarea style="cursor:not-allowed;"></textarea>
```

All i working OK in Firefox and Google Chrome, only in IE is the problem, when option get over textarea cursor change style to not allowed? Please take a look at fiddle here but only in IE?

Working fiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/f6paL8sc/**

Comment: Which version of IE you are looking?

Comment: Internet Explorer 10, and Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Here was (is) the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884256/cursor-not-functioning-correctly-in-ie11-select-inputs#comment36770268_23884256

Answer (score -1):

It seems this is a IE related Bug. I've made a solution and it works *(***IE required a .cur file to work** ); but lets check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vekicimemadu/1/edit)** first.

In this example I used `disabled` attribute to disabled the `textarea` because you are using `cursor:not-allowed` which gives a impresson of that field is `disabled`.

**Download this PNG image and convert it into (.cur) using this [Online tool](http://www.cursor.cc/)**

[image]

Here is the CSS used.

```
textarea[disabled]
{
 display:block;
  cursor:url('http://www.dolliehost.com/dolliecrave/cursors/cursors-cute/cute25.gif'), url('cute25.cur'), wait;
  background:gold;
}
```

In HTML code I disabled the `textarea` which makes more sense here.

```
<textarea disabled>This TextArea is disabled</textarea>
```

> NOTE: I haven't got chance to test on IE but it must work.

Comment: Have you made a `.cur` file? To work in IE you required this extension. I am  sure it will work in all version of IE.