# Mouse pointer over non editable elements in TinyMCE

Tags: html, tinymce, internet-explorer-9, contenteditable, mouse-cursor

I am trying to integrate some non editable zones in my TinyMCE 4. And it works fine. But now I want a cursor to become "not-allowed" over the non editable elements. I set it in css and it all works fine for Chrome and Firefox but not for IE9 the cursor don't change!

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Thanks

You can find a simple exemple here http://fiddle.tinymce.com/iSeaab

Comment: The problem is: IE overwrites your cursor, just because its in a textarea. So you need to change textarea css on hover, which leads to massive usage of JavaScript just to fit that shitty browser. You can find more information about this Bug over here on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303234/ie-strange-behavior-on-textarea-and-select

Answer (score 4):

IE only supports CUR and ANI as formats from CSS to change cursor.

```
{
    cursor: url('/cursors/customMoveCursor.png'),      /* Modern browsers    */
            url('/cursors/customMoveCursor.cur'),      /* Internet Explorer  */
            move;                                      /* Older browsers     */
}
```

Please look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property). or a good link [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-css-cursor-rule--webdesign-9441)

Have you tried to edit the CSS for TinyMCE like (tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css)

add what you need. Example:

```
    .mce-grid td.mce-grid-cell div[disabled]
{
cursor:not-allowed
}
```

I still recommend using .cur file for IE.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to use a custom cursor just a standard 'not-allowed'. But custom cursors didn't work either in TinyMCE.